# Rails - Ajax not updating view?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have limited knowledge on Ajax and I have been trying to integrate into my rails app. I want to allow the user to be able to create activities and have them show up in the view without requiring a page refresh. I read that Ajax will allow me to do this and following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) guide, I have tried to integrate it into my app.

However, it does not seem to work and I do not have any ideas as to why. I have managed to get as far as preventing the page refreshing when the user types in an activity name and clicks on the submit button but the div section does not update to display the newly created activity until after the user refreshes the page manually.

My knowledge on Ajax is quite limited so if anyone could point out what is wrong with the code or how it is supposed to be, that would be appreciated.

Below is my code for the views, controllers, and the js.erb files. If you need anymore files, let me know.

Thanks in advance

**Show.js.erb:**

```
$("#activities").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('activity')) %>");

$("<%= escape_javascript(render @activity) %>").appendTo("#activities");

$('#activities').html("<%= j (render @activity) %>");
```

**Create.js.erb**

```
$("<% escape_javascript(render 'activity')%>").appendTo("#activities");

$('#activities').append('<%= j render(@activity) %>')
```

Activities Controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def display
    @activities = Activity.all
    @activity = Activity.new
    @category = Category.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
    @activity = Activity.new

  end

  def show
    @activities = Activity.all
    @activity = Activity.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json
    end
  end

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
  end

  def create #Modified all new
    @activity = Activity.create(activity_params)

  end

  def edit
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @activity = Activity.update(activity_params)
    if @activity.save
      flash[:success] = 'Activity successfully updated!'
      redirect_to root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'ERROR: Activity failed to update'
      render_to_string
    end
  end

  private
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:a_name)
    end

end
```

Activities Show View:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<div class = "row top-buffer text-center">
  <div class='col-md-3'>
    <h1>
      Activities
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="activities">
    <% @activities.each do |a| %>
        <div>
          <h2>
            <%= a.a_name %>
          </h2>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<div>
  <%= render 'new' %>
</div>
```

Activities New Render:

```
<body>
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @activity, remote: true do |a| %>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <div class = "row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <%= a.text_field :a_name, id: 'a_name_field', placeholder: 'Activity Name'%>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class ="row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <%= a.submit 'Create', id: 'submitButton', onclick: 'saveActivity()', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to ensure that your controller acknowledge js requests:

```
# activities_controller.rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js
....
```

And substitutes all your create.js.erb lines with this:

```
# create.js.erb
$('#activities').html("<%= j (render @activities) %>");
```

Instead of using append, this is simpler. What it does is telling element with id named 'activities' to render the @activities again, which should include the newly created activity record as well.

Moreover, check this instead to learn AJAX for RoR:

https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thank you for the help. Using what you posted above as well as the guide combine with what I had from the guide I used, I managed to get it working. Thanks